# Microsoft Excel 2010 Counting unique values based on a changing condition in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Would like to have one formula to count the number of unique values in one column based on the value in another column.  This other column is a calculated number (formula) so it changes.

Below is a sample set.

1. Column A (Attempts) is where I would like to have this formula
   counting the final value.
2. Column B is a formula base number (Attempt Order 0),
3. Column C (Key Record) is the unique value to be counted based on the
   column C's unique values associated with Column C.

   The below example was me manually calculating column A values which I would like a formula to do it instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by column B being a "formula base number." I'll assume that columns B and C are generated by your external source, and you just want to count the times that each key record appears in the list. You can accomplish this with  *COUNTIF()*

Assuming the columns in your screenshot are A, B, and C, then paste this into A2 and drag it down. It counts how many times the value at the intersection of the current row and your Key Record column appears in the entire Key Record column.

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,C2)
```

[image]